# Fleck WebSockets

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I want to use Fleck for my WebSocket project,
Server side looks pretty straightforward, but how to I differentiate opened connections. is there some sort of ID? The only way I can think of is to create GUID in OnOpen event and pass it back to client. is there a smarter solution?

Basic server set up:

```
socket.OnOpen = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Open!"); 
    allSockets.Add(socket);
};

socket.OnClose = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Close!");
    allSockets.Remove(socket);
};

socket.OnMessage = message =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send("Echo: " + message));
};
```

E.G. how would I make a chat room so all connection receive message except for the one sending.

Fleck server here: https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fleck now creates a Guid Id on the WebSocketConnectionInfo for every connected client. This will help in cases where multiple connections are using the same IP. See the related commit here:

https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck/commit/fc037f49362bb41a2bc753a5ff51cc9da40ad824

Answer (score 2):

Ask the user for a user name, and attach the username to the the socket address:

```
var wsimpl = window.WebSocket || window.mozWebSocket;
window.ws = new wsimpl('http://localhost:8080/myApp_' + userName, myProtocol);
```

then strip out the userName on the service side after the socket has been opened with socket.WebSocketConnectionInfo.path.  There is also a clientip property that can be used also.  I am doing this and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for Answering, but I already have modified WebSocket to have GUID.

Answer (score 1):

I started something similar to what you are asking I am doing. In my case I am using the  `ConnectionInfo.Path` to differ between what my sockets are doing.

You can gain a lot of information already out of the ConnectionInfo

`socket.ConnectionInfo.{Host|Path|Origin|SubProtocol|ClientIPAddress|Cookies}`

So to answer your question to give it to everyone but the sender you can differentiate each socket based on the ConnectionInfo (if applicable you could create a UID out of this info also)

---

As a very basic example:

If you know each Client will have a different IP something like the following would work:

```
 socket.OnMessage = message =>
 {
     foreach (IWebSocketConnection socketConnection in allSockets.Where(socketConnection => socket.ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress != socketConnection.ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress))
     {
         socketConnection.Send("Echo: " + message);
     }
 };
```

Comment: ConnectionInfo now has a Guid Id. It should help in cases where a multiple clients share the same IP. https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck/commit/fc037f49362bb41a2bc753a5ff51cc9da40ad824

Comment: @statenjason Should probably add that as an answer so people are more aware that it is now part of Fleck rather than the OP implementing his own version.

Answer (score 0):

It's a different socket instance per client, so I would have thought you should be able to do:

```
allSockets.Where(x => x != socket).ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send("Echo: " + message));
```